# Find the 3rd order partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Find all the 3rd order partial derivatives

$f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$,

can I write for all my 3rd partial derivatives as

$0=${$f_{xxx},f_{xxy},f_{xyy},f_{yyy}$}

Comment: You could express it verbally as "All derivatives of order higher than 2 vanish", or mathematically $f_{xxx}=f_{yyy}=f_{xyy}=f_{xyy} = 0$

Comment: @Nox, So i guess what I wrote is wrong?

Comment: I'm actually not sure, that's why I put my suggestion as a comment. I guess strictly speaking it'd be wrong, but most should understand what you mean and that's what matters.

Comment: @Nox, Thanks!  ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example we have for $$f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$$ the following derivatives:
$$f_x=2ax+by$$
$$f_{xx}=2a$$
$$f_{xxx}=0$$
can you get further?

Comment: No I don't think so